# How to link to different page using Angular framework in my case?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using angular to provide the link for my page.

I have something like

//main app configuration
app.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.filters',
  'myApp.services',
  'myApp.directives'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

}]);
```

//test page configuration
test-controller.js

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
    config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/test/:link', {
        templateUrl: 'test/:link.html',
        constroller: 'Ctrl'
    }).
    when('/test2/:link', {
        templateUrl: 'test2/:link.html',
        constroller: 'Ctrl'
       })
    }).
    controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        //scope data
    }])
```

for some reason, the `$routeprovide` in my `test-controller.js` doesn't work and output module injection error.

Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: it's not working because it's not included as a dependency. what is the purpose of having two apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, it is because you didn't add 'ngRoute' as dependency in the second definition